# Xcode 12.3 couldn't install app on iOS 14.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios14

I've updated my iPhone to iOS 14.3 and it required me to update Xcode to 12.3 too. But Xcode now gives me the following error whenever trying to run/debug the app through the device.

> Errors were encountered while preparing your device for development. Please check the Devices and Simulators Window.

[image]

I tried restarting Xcode, reconnecting the device, changing deployment target etc. with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you updated you iOS to latest beta version, you should also use latest Xcode beta version.

Or else restart your device.

Comment: I'm using full versions of Xcode/iOS as stated in the question